# Black outlines on tab hover when using gatsby-background-image

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I'm using [gatsby-background-image](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-background-image/) with Gatsby v3 but for some reason I am getting black outlines whenever I hover over another tab[image: outlines]

I'm not sure if anything is wrong with my code, or if it's the plugin itself. I removed the CSS to no avail, so that can't be the problem.

```
const ImageSlider = (props) => {

  const [sliderIndex, setSliderIndex] = useState(0);
  const images = ['../images/1.png', '../images/2.png']

  const {backgroundImage} = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      backgroundImage: file(relativePath: {eq: "1.png"}) {
        id
        childImageSharp {
          gatsbyImageData(
            width: 1360,
            quality: 50,
            webpOptions: {quality: 70}
          )
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const image = getImage(backgroundImage)
  const bg = convertToBgImage(image)

  return (
    <div className={styles.imgSlider}>
      <BackgroundImage Tag="section" {...bg} className={styles.bgImg}>
        {props.children}
      </BackgroundImage>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to set `preserveStackingContext` to true